# Getting black plots with plt.imshow after multiplying RGB image array by a scalar

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb, imshow

So I am a bit confused as to why this is happening.

I have a binary image:
[image]

Now I want to convert this binary image into RGB space, so therefore I use the `dstack` function to concatenate the 3rd axis

[image]

Everything works fine so far, but now I have to multiply the `out_image` array by `255` to reflect white in RGB space, and this is where the problem occurs everything turns black[image]

But if I plot another random image, everything is fine so what is happening here, I've also played around with the `cmap` but regardless of what kind of `cmap` I use it always turns out to be black when multiplied by `255`

Any ideas?

Comment: When I use `plt.imshow(...)` for RGB images, I've used float values between 0 and 1 in each of the RGB channels.   In fact, its given me errors when I don't do it that way.  It seems to be plotting it that way in your second image with black and white from 0 to 1.  If you adjust one of the other channels I would imagine that you would see the other colors.  So, they question comes down to whether or not you need to have it mapped to 8-bit integers or not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**The solution for the problem in the question would be not to multiply the array with `255`.**
The other option is to reduce the datatype of the image to unsigned int8,
`out_image = out_image.astype(np.uint8)`

Let me explain why:

A single channel image can have arbitrary values and datatype. The color will be determined by the colormap to be used, and if required, normalized to a certain range.

[image]

In contrast, 3 channel RGB arrays are assumed by `imshow` to be in two ranges, `[0., 1.]` or `[0,255]`. ("3-dimensional arrays must be of dtype unsigned byte, unsigned short, float32 or float64").
The range to use will be selected by the datatype of the array:

1. A **float** array should be in the **`[0., 1.]`** range,
2. an **integer** array should be in the range **`[0,255]`**. Also note that integer arrays must be of datatype int8 and not int32.

[image]

As can be seen in the RGB case, an integer array in the range `[0,1]` stays black, as well as a float array of range `[0., 255.]`.