# Emphasize the blue in an image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, image-processing

I'm using `matplotlib` to do it but for some reason, my code creates an unexpected image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imread,imsave


# original image
image1=imread('img.jpg')
plt.imshow(image1)
plt.show()

# empesize the blue in that image
plt.imshow(image1*[0.95,0.95,1])
plt.show()
```

result:

The top image is the original one and the second (which is shown) is the unexpected result.

[image]

It seems that no matter what values I enter to the vector, I get the same strange result. **Why?**

Comment: Maybe it's because of data type. Try to force uint8 with `np.array(image1*[0.95,0.95,1]).astype(np.uint8)`.

Comment: First of all, It's working so thanks. I don't understand why. I thought `uint8` is helping when I sum over `255` but I don't sum anything. Am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is closely related to [Getting black plots with plt.imshow after multiplying image array by a scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044259/getting-black-plots-with-plt-imshow-after-multiplying-image-array-by-a-scalar/42045225#42045225).

You may compare `image1.dtype`, which is `uint8`, to `(image1*[0.95,0.95,1]).dtype`, which is `float`.

Matplotlib `imshow` can plot integer values, in which case they need to be in the range `[0, 255]` or float values, in which case they need to be in the range `[0.0, 1.0]`. So while plotting the original image of integer values works fine, the multiplied image, which will consist of float values up to `255.`, exceeds the allowed range of `[0.0, 1.0]` by 25500%. Hence it is mostly white (because pixel values are cropped to `1.0`).

The solution is either to cast the values back to `uint` after multiplication,

```
image2 = (image1*[0.95,0.95,1]).astype(np.uint8)
```

or to divide by `255.`,

```
image2 = (image1*[0.95,0.95,1])/255.
```

You could also use `plt.Normalize` like

```
image2 = plt.Normalize(0,255)(image1*[0.95,0.95,1])
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you also tell me what will be the difference if I used `np.dot` instead of `*`?

Comment: np.dot is a completely different operation. It would mix the rgb channels. What would be the purpose of that?

Comment: After reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201744/806963 to grayscale an image, he used the vector `[0.3,0.6,0.1]` and `np.dot` it with the image. I understand the implementation differences between `*` and `np.dot` but still don't understand, for example, what will be the impact on the actual image if I would use `np.dot`.

Comment: Those are just two very different things. The multiplication with a vector will leave each channel intact, they will just be weighted differently. In contrast the dot product will mix the rgb channels and the output will be a single grey scale channel. So `*` means RGB -> RGB, while `dot` means RGB -> Grey.

Comment: Why `dot`, in general, result in a grey image?

Comment: ...due to the definition of a dot product in mathematics. vector * vector = vector; but rowvector dot columnvector = scalar.