# Python matplotlib imshow always give me white no matter if i send array of 1s or 0s

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
_im1 = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]).astype(np.uint8)

_im2 = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]).astype(np.uint8)


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 8))

ax1.set_title('1s')
ax1.imshow(_im1 , cmap='binary')

ax2.set_title('Os')
ax2.imshow(_im2, cmap='binary')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=1)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

I am getting both the images to be white color.
I have tried using cmap='grey' then both show as black
I was using this has reference : [Getting black plots with plt.imshow after multiplying image array by a scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044259/getting-black-plots-with-plt-imshow-after-multiplying-image-array-by-a-scalar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ax1.set_title('1s')
ax1.imshow(_im1, cmap='binary', vmin=0, vmax=1)

ax2.set_title('Os')
ax2.imshow(_im2, cmap='binary', vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

Edit: updated to satisfy comment. `cmap='gray'` with vmax/vmin works as well

Comment: This input you are generating is not like the input in the question. If you had the input in the question, how would you generate the correct plot?

Comment: i tried cmap='gray' , did not work for me.
however, , vmin=0, vmax=1 works

Comment: oh sorry, I meant ```cmap='gray'``` with the vmax/vmin