# matplotlib plt.show() visual glitch when pre-indexing empty numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

So I'm experiencing a weird visual glitch when creating an empty numpy array and loading an image in it as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from imageio import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dir_path = os.path.join('path/to/image', 'a.jpg')
# Pre-indexing numpy array
X = np.empty((1, *(111, 455), 4))

# Loading image in the traditional way:
img_0 = imread(dir_path)
# Loading image and saving it in the pre-indexed array:
X[0] = imread(dir_path)

# Check whether image contents are the same
print((img_0 == X[0]).all())

# Display images
imgplot = plt.imshow(X[0])
plt.show()
imgplot = plt.imshow(img_0)
plt.show()
```

So in this code I'm importing an image [a.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRHUv.png) either through the traditional imread or by saving it in a numpy array. Theoretically the two methods should be equivalent, in fact `print((img_0 == X[0]).all())` returns `True`.

However, this are the `plt.show()` results:

`numpy` image:
[image: numpy image]

traditional image:
[image: traditional image]

If the contents of the two arrays are exactly the same, how is it possible that the two images are displayed differently when imported by the same imread function?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044259/getting-black-plots-with-plt-imshow-after-multiplying-image-array-by-a-scalar/42045225#42045225

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you put the image into your array `X`, it went from `int` to `float`, and the scaling methods differ with `plt.imshow` between ints and floats. This is described in the warning message you probably got:

> Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).

What you can do is either instantiate `X` as an `int` array, or force `X[0]` to dtype `int`, or normalize the image to be between 0 and 1 by dividing by 255:

```
# Method 1:
X = np.empty((1, *(111, 455), 3), dtype=int)
X[0] = imread(dir_path)

imgplot = plt.imshow(X[0])
plt.show()

# Method 2:
X = np.empty((1, *(111, 455), 3))
X[0] = imread(dir_path)

imgplot = plt.imshow(X[0].astype(int))
plt.show()

# method 3:
imgplot = plt.imshow(X[0]/255)
plt.show()
```

Following either of those methods, you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's clear. I didn't know that for example float(1.0) == int(1) would return True in Python. I was very confused by this. 

It's weird, I didn't get any warning when running that code, but now everything works :) thanks!